# wix unable to use string in detect condition

Tags: wix

I am using WIX installer to genrate exe, till now everything is working fine but now i need to add one detect condition in exe package as given below.

```
<ExePackage 
  Id="AccessRuntime2013" 
  DetectCondition="((MsAccessInstalled = Outlook.Application.15) AND (MSOffice2013RuntimeInstalled = 0))" >
```

MsAccessInstalled is a variable which stores version of outlook installed and MSOffice2013RuntimeInstalled is a variable which checks whether access runtime is installed or not. Both variables are setting properly.

I have to run this exe only when MsAccessInstalled = "Outlook.Application.15" and MSOffice2013RuntimeInstalled is not installed. If i run both condition separate then it works but if i clubbed both it doesn't works. It gives error message as `Failed to parse condition "((MsAccessInstalled = Outlook.Application.15) AND (MSOffice2013RuntimeInstalled = 0))". Unexpected character at position`. Please help.

Comment: "Burn are distinct from strings and numbers, unlike how Windows Installer, that means you need to use the "v" prefix". Please add all the variables declaration.

Comment: No offense, just wondering: when you typed that all out, did you read it through? Was that easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you change the DetectCondition to

```
<ExePackage 
  Id="AccessRuntime2013" 
  DetectCondition="MsAccessInstalled ~= &quot;Outlook.Application.15&quot; AND MSOffice2013RuntimeInstalled = 0" 
  ... />
```

You can also test your conditions by making some test `util:Condition` tags in your bootstrapper.

```
<util:Condition Message="MSAccessInstalled condition failed">MsAccessInstalled ~= &quot;Outlook.Application.15&quot;</Condition>
<util:Condition Message="MSOffice2013RuntimeInstalled condition failed">MSOffice2013RuntimeInstalled = 0</Condition>
```

Run your bootstrapper and see if either condition fails. Do remember to remove these conditions once you're done testing as they will cause issues if put into production.